# `Pandas argmax` to get all `True` indices after masking (Python 3) (e.g. (pd.Series > 0).argmax()))

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, mask, argmax

What I want to do but `argmax` only gives me the first value that is `True`:

```
Se = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=list("abcdef"))
#a    0
#b    1
#c    2
#d    3
#e    4
#f    5
#dtype: int64

mask = (Se % 2 == 0)
#a     True
#b    False
#c     True
#d    False
#e     True
#f    False
#dtype: bool

mask.argmax()
#'a'
```

What I have to do instead:

```
Se[mask].index
# Index(['a', 'c', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

This isn't too inconvenient but I have to instantiate the `Series` first which reduces my productivity.  It would be nice to be able to do this:

```
(pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=list("abcdef")) % 2 == 0).argmax()
```

My question is: **How can I do this using `argmax`? If this can't be done w/ `argmax`, could I do this w/ a different function in `pandas`?**

Comment: Is that what you want: `Se.index[(Se % 2 == 0)]` or do you need to do it in a "chained" manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`compress`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.compress.html):

```
idx = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=list("abcdef")).compress(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).index
```

The resulting output:

```
Index(['a', 'c', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest pandas version, you can directly pass the filter function to `[]` or `.loc[]`:

```
Se[lambda x: x%2 == 0].index  # or Se.loc[lambda x: x%2 == 0].index
# Index([u'a', u'c', u'e'], dtype='object')
```